# Does an Intel 1.80GHz quad core processor meet the 2GHz dual core processor system requirements?

Tags: 18.04, performance, cpu, system-requirements

My laptop has an Intel® Core™ i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4 processor. On the Ubuntu website, it says that I need a 2 GHz dual core processor as a requirement to install Ubuntu 18.04. Does this mean that I cannot install it?

Here are the full specs of my laptop:
[image]

Comment: All Intel Core i3, i5, i7, and i9 processors are fine for 18.04, regardless of speed. Older ones might lead you to prefer Xubuntu or Lubuntu for added performance.

Answer (score 1):

A 1.8GHz quad core processor is the approximate equivalent of a 3.6 GHz dual core processor in overall performance. I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed on a computer with a 1.6 GHz quad core processor and 4 GB RAM and it runs OK, there's nothing wrong with the performance at all.

Comment: Can I install Ubuntu server 18 LTS on a Intel E6600 dual core with 3GB RAM

Comment: @KasunRajapaksha You can install Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a computer that has an Intel E6600 dual core CPU and 3GB RAM with plenty of room to spare. For more information about Ubuntu Server 18.04 system requirements see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar/206421#206421).

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it friend, It will run smoothly

My system configuration is HP laptop Intel® Core™ i3-6006U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4, 8GB RAM, 2GB Radeon dedicated graphics.

if you were facing problem again then you may need to check your Ubuntu image.
I will provide you link which may help you.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an i5 2nd generation  (i5-2410M Sandy Bridge, i.e. older than yours) and I have no problems with Ubuntu 18.04 at all. So you will be absolutely fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can run Ubuntu 18.04 with your machine. Here's is what Canonical is mentioning about the hardware recommendation (not obligatory):

Recommended system requirements:

```
2 GHz dual core processor or better
2 GB system memory
25 GB of free hard drive space
Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
Internet access is helpful
```

But, according to my experience, when you have the choice, always choose that:
- a processor with a minimum of 2 GHz (not taking into account the "turbo mode") - But your machine will do fine
- 4GB Ram (3.7GB in your case means you have 4GB)
- leave at least 25GB of free hard drive space (less heating, faster working)